# In XMonad, Mod-p (dmenu_run) displays an empty menu

Tags: xmonad, dmenu

When I hit MOD-p in XMonad, I used to get a list of commands. Now I just get an empty menu. If I type the name of an executable on my path and hit the carriage return, the command executes as expected. But why aren't any programs listed in the menu? *Solution is posted below.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, XMonad maps MOD-p to `dmenu_run`. (You can see the default key bindings in the [source code on github](https://github.com/xmonad/xmonad/blob/master/src/XMonad/Config.hs).) So I tried launching `dmenu_run` from the command line and saw the same behaviour; a blank menu that allows me to type the name of an executable in my path.

**The problem was that the file `~/.cache/dmenu_run` was empty. When I deleted this file and ran `dmenu_run` again, it worked perfectly** (and created a new, non-empty `~/.cache/dmenu_run`). I think the problem happened when I added a definition of `$XDG_CACHE_HOME` to my `.zshrc` file and the cache somehow got blanked out.